# Back to back play video using vuejs LARAVEL

Tags: vuejs2

i have video list.

once i played 1st video after finshed it will play 2nd video then 3rd in vuejs laravel.
i am using vue-core-video-player for video playing. i didnt understand how can i create loop for play video and i need to add next button too in player.

```html
<vue-core-video-player
  id="videoarea" 
  controls
  :src="src"
  ref="video"
  :autoplay=false
>
</vue-core-video-player>
```

Answer (score 0):

The loop prop is available here: https://core-player.github.io/vue-core-video-player/configuration.html#video-playback-control

As for the next button, since it's not on the documentation, I guess you will need to make your own with something like:

- pause the video
- replace the current video by the next one in your array
- play the video again

Comment: umm  not get it.

Comment: What did you not get ? If you could share some code, we could move forward. Like this, I'm not sure what I can provide more.

Comment: see this https://jsfiddle.net/jimcute/34o7pza2/  link. i need like this output but using vue js

Comment: The code there is pretty much what I've written in my bullet points. The `.addEventListener('ended'...)` is a nice one btw. What did you tried so far, do you have some code to share ?